# ajax jquery live search box not working in wordpress plugin

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

Hi i'm desiging a plugin and m new here i want to use ajax java live search box script in my wordpress plugin, so please answer me...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="html-table-search.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('table.search-table').tableSearch({
                searchText:'Search Table',
                searchPlaceHolder:'Input Value'
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: how can i use this script in my wordpres plugin?? Thnks

Comment: The question is not clear. Please update the question with more clarity..

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't ask clearly I understood that you want to know how to include script to your plugin. If so, do this:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'your_plugin_name', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/your-script.js', array( 'jquery' ),'1.0.0', true );
```

Comment: Thnx....But i want to use the given script in wordpress so tell me please how can i use this scipt in wordpress?how i put i? i'm using like - -

Comment: wp_register_script('html-table-search','https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js');
wp_enqueue_script( 'html-table-search'); is this correct way????

Comment: Second parameter of `wp_register_script()` is **path to the file you want to include**. If you want to include script which uses jQuery do this: `wp_register_script('jQuery','code.jquery.com/jque‌​ry-2.1.3.min.js'); wp_enqueue_script( 'jQuery'); wp_register_script('myScript','/path/to/my/script.js', array('jQuery')); wp_enqueue_script( 'myScript');` **NOTE** that `'/path/to/my/script.js'` is relative to current folder (that's why I used `plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )`). Also make sure that path to `jquery-2.1.3.min.js` is correct

Comment: ok... Now this is am using ---- - - -   wp_register_script('jQuery','https://code.jquery.com/jque‌​ry-2.1.3.‌​min.js');
 wp_enqueue_script( 'jQuery'); 
 wp_register_script('myScript','html-table-search.js', array('jQuery'));
 wp_enqueue_script( 'myScript');

Comment: its.. 'http//code.jquery.com/jque‌​ry-2.1.3.‌​‌​min.js'  but still not working

Comment: The file you put those functions in must be included in main plugin file. So if your main plugin file is `my-plugin.php` and you put those functions in `enqueue-scripts.php`, now you have to add following to **my-plugin.php:** `require_once('/path/to/enqueue-scripts.php');`

Comment: still not working

Comment: ok can you please tell me search box code ,? I want to use a search box by which i can search my records ...from database table???

Comment: Try this. Create a `function enqueue_my_scripts()` and put `wp_register_script` and `wp_enqueue_script` into that function. Now right below the function you just created add following: `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts' ); add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_scripts' );`. Again, remember to include this file to your main plugin file

Comment: still not working.... :-(